# How to delete a file with invalid name using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

I've got a `file` named `umengchannel_316_豌豆荚` I want to delete this file..
I tried the following: `os.remove()`, `os.unlink()` , `shutil.move()` but nothing seems to work..
Are there any other approaches to this problem?

Comment: Which Python version? How did you try? You should post your non-working code first.

Comment: what is the error that you are having? are you using python 2 or 3? DId you defined an encoding?

Comment: I had no issues with removing a file I created called *umengchannel_316_豌豆荚.txt* with `os.remove`. How are you checking it is invalid? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Rather than try to hard-code the filename, would it be possible to get it into a python string using something like `glob`?  You might then have better luck with those functions.  How did they fail?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Unix OS, have been able to create a blank file with the name you specified and delete it with `os.remove()` in python intepreter.

```
$ cd ~
$ touch "umengchannel_316_豌豆荚.txt"
$ python

>>> import os
>>> os.remove("/home/neko/umengchannel_316_豌豆荚.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`os.system("rm umengchannel_316_豌豆荚")`